# Pull right button on bootstrap breadcrumb

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to set the button on the right but this way isn't working:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li class="active">Data</li>
    <li><a href="index.php" class="btn-sm btn-primary pull-right">Back</a></li>
</ul>
```

Only the last `<li>`, the button, has to be on the right.

Comment: Which bootstrap version do you use?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to float li tag, not a.

I'd suggest to update to bootstrap 4, there we can use [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) juice :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .breadcrumb > *:last-child.pull-right::before { display: none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Level 1</a></li>
        <li class="active">Level 2</li>
        <li class="pull-right"><a href="index.php" class="btn-sm btn-primary">Back</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can still utilize flex without upgrading to V4 you know :)

Comment: Of course we can, but in [v4 breadcrumb](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4.0.0/scss/_breadcrumb.scss) we have flex by default :)

Comment: That's true, just pointing out you can use it without having to upgrade if you want, just in-case you prefer V3, like I do lol